How to debug ROS2 Publisher/Subscriber issue
I am facing the following situation:

A publisher that periodically sends a message to topic, queue size is set to 1.
A subscriber (queue size 10) listening on that message, and in a callback, attempts to pass that on to a remote destination remote, through regular http request (done via python requests)
remote may not always be accessible. When it is not, the requests will fail, after some delay (built-in retries/timeout/ etc.).
This seems to cause the subscriber thread to error out? I then wrapped the requests in try/except blocks, which seemed to have solved the issue.
However, tonight I just observed the issue again. The symptom is as follows:


The node running the publisher is still running, since the log message is appearing every few seconds as expected.
If I manually echo the topic, nothing gets printed out. So, presumably the publisher is not actually publishing the message.
If I try to manually publish message to topic, I do not get any response from the subscriber. Is there a way to check if the subscriber is still active? Or if the node is still running? Or if the queue is full?
This may be a coincident, but in the log I see 10 instances of "Error making POST request", which is my log message for when the requests to remote fails. This count of 10 matches the queue size I have set for the subscriber. However, things are wrapped in try/except blocks, so if I'm understanding correctly, the queue should still be cleared once the callback returned (even if from the except condition)?

In any case, I am scratching my head and not understanding what's going on. I can simply restart things and they will continue to work for quite some time, but as the remote comes and goes, it seems that this scenario is still going to happen unless I figure out exactly what's going on. Hence, any pointers would be much appreciated!!
Update
I'm back with some more observations, and hopefully helpful code.
Code:
1. My state node
class StateMachine(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('state_node')
        self.logger = self.get_logger()
        self.logger.info('state_node is spinning up...')

        self.pubs = MyPublishers(self)

        # interval calls
        check_interval = 5
        timer_cb_group = MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup()
        self.timer = self.create_timer(
            check_interval, self.status_check, callback_group=timer_cb_group)
    
    def status_check(self):
        self.logger.info('State node step function called')
        if <robot_is_connected>:
            self.pubs.send_led_signal('ready')



class MyPublishers:
    
    def __init__(self, state_node):
        self.logger.info('MyPublishers is loaded...')
        self.led_color_flip = True
        self.parent_node = state_node
        self.pub_change_led = self.parent_node.create_publisher(
            Color, '/led', 1
        )

    def send_led_signal(self, sig_type):
        msg = Color()
        if sig_type == 'ready':
            if self.led_color_flip:
                msg.red = 76
                msg.green = 187
                msg.blue = 23
            else:
                msg.red = 238
                msg.green = 248
                msg.blue = 236

        self.logger.info('send_ready_signal publishing message:')
        self.logger.info(str(msg))
        self.led_color_flip = not self.led_color_flip
        self.pub_change_led.publish(msg)



def main():
    rclpy.init()
    try:
        
        state_node = StateMachine()
        executor = MultiThreadedExecutor(num_threads=4)
        executor.add_node(state_node)
        try:
            executor.spin()
        finally:
            executor.shutdown()
            state_node.destroy_node()
    finally:
        rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

2. My robot ROS interface
class RobotCore(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('robot_core')
        self.logger = self.get_logger()
        self.expression_control = Expression(self)


class Expression:
    def __init__(self, core_node):
        self.core_node = core_node
        core_node.get_logger().info('Expression module is loaded')

        core_node.create_subscription(
            Color,
            '/led',
            self.change_led,
            10
        )

    def change_led(self, params):
        if (
            params.red in range(0, 256)
            and params.blue in range(0, 256)
            and params.green in range(0, 256)
        ):
            post(
                <remote-ip>,
                "led",
                {"red": params.red, "green": params.green, "blue": params.blue},
                timeout=2
            )


def post(ip, endpoint, json=None, timeout=20):
    url = "http://" + ip + "/api/" + endpoint
    logger.info(f"POSTing: {url}")
    logger.info(f"JSON data is: {str(json)[:100]}")
    try:
        if json is None:
            res = requests.post(url, timeout=timeout)
        else:
            res = requests.post(url, json=json, timeout=timeout)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error making POST request")
        logger.error(str(e))
        res = None
    return res


def main():
    rclpy.init()
    try:
        robot_core = RobotCore()
        executor = MultiThreadedExecutor(num_threads=3)
        executor.add_node(robot_core)
        try:
            executor.spin()
        finally:
            executor.shutdown()
            robot_core.destroy_node()
    finally:
        rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

3. My Launch File
def generate_launch_description():
    robot_ros_node = Node(
        package='robot_ros',
        executable='core',
        name='robot_ros_core',
        parameters=params,
    )

    state_node = Node(
        package='main_package',
        executable='state_node',
        name='state_node',
        # parameters=params,
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        robot_ros_node,
        state_node,
    ])

4. The Service that Starts the nodes
[Unit]
Description=Starts various nodes

[Service]
Type=simple
User=<USERNAME>
WorkingDirectory=/home/<USERNAME>/...
ExecStart=/usr/bin/base_startup.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target


5. The script called by the service
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source install/setup.bash
ros2 launch main_package main_launch.py

More Observations and notes:

This thing is running on a Raspberry Pi 4B, Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble;
The issue described in the original post seemed to have happened again, even when I haven't interacted with the nodes at all (i.e. the /led topic didn't publisher and subscribers haven't gotten any activities since my last boot, since the <robot_is_connected> has always been False since my last boot)
ros2 node list shows nothing!? But the step function message State node step function called is periodically printed out to the log as expected, so the state node is running? In fact, the log shows these messages every 5 secs.

[state_node]: State node step function called
[state_node]: Sending ready signal
[state_node]: send_ready_signal publishing message:
[state_node]: robot_interfaces.msg.Color(red=76, green=187, blue=23)


ros2 topic hz /led doesn't return, presumably because there is no message being sent there. If I echo the topic /led, I also do not get the message. Presumably self.pub_change_led.publish(msg) isn't actually publishing the message.
If I manually pub a message through command line, ros2 topic hz  and echo both picks it up, but apparently the subscriber in RobotCore.Expression does not.
When I tried to dig through syslog, I found this copied below.

systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
systemd[859470]: Stopped target Main User Target.
systemd[859470]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
systemd[859470]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
systemd[859470]: Stopped target Basic System.
systemd[859470]: Stopped target Paths.
systemd[859470]: Stopped target Sockets.
systemd[859470]: Stopped target Timers.
systemd[859470]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
systemd[859470]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
systemd[859470]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
systemd[859470]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
systemd[859470]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
systemd[859470]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
systemd[859470]: Closed debconf communication socket.
systemd[859470]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
systemd[859470]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
systemd[859470]: Reached target Shutdown.
systemd[859470]: Finished Exit the Session.
systemd[859470]: Reached target Exit the Session.
systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
systemd[1]: user-1000.slice: Consumed 48min 23.541s CPU time.


It feels relevant because there were still periodic messages from RobotCore before this chunk, but none afterwards.
So I looked it up and it seems like it might be related to the fact that I had ssh'ed into the Pis and then logged out, then the system deciding to kill all my processes after a while. Since the nodes were spin up by services as the same user, they might have got affected.
However, what's weird to me is that apparently state node is still running and printing to the log? Why are some nodes affected while others are not? They are all launched from the same launch file..

This is roughly what I get when I look at htop (this is incomplete but hopefully includes most relevant lines):
 PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU%▽MEM%   TIME+  Command
24516 <username>     20   0  9132  4764  2780 R  5.3  0.1  0:00.65 htop -u <username>
1066 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  1:22.10 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
672 <username>     20   0  7384  3120  2672 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.06 /bin/bash /usr/bin/base_startup.sh
923 <username>     20   0  411M 34296 13236 S  0.0  0.9  3:58.05 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2 launch main_package main_launch.py robot_ip:=192.168.1.1
1049 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  9:00.68 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1050 <username>     20   0  411M 34296 13236 S  0.0  0.9  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2 launch main_package main_launch.py robot_ip:=192.168.1.1
1052 <username>     20   0  411M 34296 13236 S  0.0  0.9  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2 launch main_package main_launch.py robot_ip:=192.168.1.1
1053 <username>     20   0  765M 79264 25508 S  1.9  2.0 14:57.64 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/main_package/lib/main_package/state_node --ros-args -r __node:=state_node
1054 <username>     20   0  411M 34296 13236 S  0.0  0.9  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2 launch main_package main_launch.py robot_ip:=192.168.1.1
1056 <username>     20   0  411M 34296 13236 S  0.0  0.9  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2 launch main_package main_launch.py robot_ip:=192.168.1.1
1058 <username>     20   0  411M 34296 13236 S  0.0  0.9  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2 launch main_package main_launch.py robot_ip:=192.168.1.1
1063 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1064 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  0:18.06 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1065 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  1:18.98 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1067 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  0:29.44 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1068 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  1:13.60 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1069 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1070 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  0:00.97 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1071 <username>     20   0  957M 56764 21416 S  0.0  1.5  0:00.01 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/robot_ros/lib/robot_ros/core --ros-args -r __node:=robot_ros_core --params-file /tmp/launch_params_n9tkmfqt
1108 <username>     20   0  765M 79264 25508 S  0.0  2.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/main_package/lib/main_package/state_node --ros-args -r __node:=state_node
1109 <username>     20   0  765M 79264 25508 S  0.0  2.0  0:17.74 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/<base-dir>/install/main_package/lib/main_package/state_node --ros-args -r __node:=state_node  

For now, I ran loginctl enable-linger <username> and will continue to monitor the situation.

Is this under ROS 1 or ROS 2? You tagged your question with both, but I think in this case it matters which version it is (I'm thinking of QoS settings).

It would also help if you showed your code.


Could we see the subscriber-callback function? Try/Catch SHOULD be part of this routine, so you already did it correctly. 2. You can use the ROS2 CLI tools like ros2 node list ros2 topic list ros2 hz $topicname to check aliveness of nodes (and therefore processes). 3. You can use e.g. https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/htop/ to check for aliveness of processes on OS-level.


@ChristianFritz This is ROS2 (I thought ROS was just a more general tag). I'll try to update with some minimal code from relevant parts.

@Scoeerg Thanks for the tips. I'll try to update with some minimal code from relevant parts. For now, I added timeout parameters to all the python requests I've utilized - my suspicion is that some of those may have been hanging forever and hence blocking the entire thing? I'll try things out when I encounter the issue again.

No worries. Async programming can be tricky. Can you re-create the problem by manually disabling connection to server? Pull ethernet cable ... we need minimal example code to actually understand. You might catch your errors wrong, too.

@Scoeerg I added some code snippets, and more info to the original post. Thank you for your pointers so far!
